# Upload repository on Git hub

Tags: github, repository

After reading on lot of sites and blogs i have concluded the following steps for uploading the repository on GitHub.

1. Create an Account on https://github.com
2. Download github tool for windows
3. Click on add new repository (on plus button appear on top left corner of github tool for windows.)
4. Give the path of your file or folder that you want to upload as a repository and name of the repo which you want to show on github.
5. By default it will be public if you wan to make it private then you have to purchase for 7$ account.
6. After uploading please click on Sync button appear on the top bar. And then check is it uploaded or not. By clicking on the

   "Settings" > "View on github"

Please let me know if i am missing any relevant step in this process??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me your workflow is **OK**.

After the step 6, your project is hosted on http://github.com/yourusername/yourproject.

Your project will be **public** if you have a FREE account *(otherwise, you can publish it as private and only you and contributors have access)*.

*Little advice: don't forget to learn the main github line commands to manage and commit your code, it's more practical than the Windows tools...*

Useful PDF which summerizes Github line commands: https://education.github.com/git-cheat-sheet-education.pdf

CTRL+P and keep it on your desktop for the beginning :)

Have fun!

Comment: yes i agree with you so i will add here some shell commands that are necessary for this process:                                                                           init git,   git add , git commit ,add files by adding them to your repository. Do this with git add filename. If you want to add all your files, you can do git add .

Comment: Yes! You can find this nice PDF which summarizes the useful Github commands: https://training.github.com/kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf CTRL+P and keep it on your desktop for the beginning :)